# Doc-view change background to black

Tags: docview

How can we invert the colors of the image when opening a pdf file in doc-view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `pdf-tools`

If you decide to install [`pdf-tools`](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) package (also available on Melpa) to view PDF files (instead of `doc-view-mode`), you can view the PDF in "midnight mode" by using the default binding `C-c C-r m` or by doing `M-x pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode`.

The default colors of this minor mode are,

- Foreground color - [`#839496`](http://www.color-hex.com/color/839496)
- Background color - [`#002b36`](http://www.color-hex.com/color/002b36)

But you can customize those by customizing the variable `pdf-view-midnight-colors`.

From `C-h v pdf-view-midnight-colors`,

> Colors used when `pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode' is activated.
>   This should be a cons (FOREGROUND . BACKGROUND) of colors.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following functions to reverse the colors in a PDF.  Note that it uses [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) under the hood and will not work without it:

```el
(defun define-doc-view-current-cache-dir ()
  ;; doc-view-current-cache-dir was renamed to doc-view--current-cache-dir in Emacs 24.5
  (or (fboundp 'doc-view-current-cache-dir)
      (defalias 'doc-view-current-cache-dir 'doc-view--current-cache-dir)))
(eval-after-load "doc-view" '(define-doc-view-current-cache-dir))

(defun doc-view-reverse-colors ()
  "Inverts document colors.\n
Requires an installation of ImageMagick (\"convert\")."
  (interactive)
  ;; error out when ImageMagick is not installed
  (if (/= 0 (call-process-shell-command "convert -version"))
      (error "Reverse colors requires ImageMagick (convert)")
    (when (eq major-mode 'doc-view-mode)
      ;; assume current doc-view internals about cache-names
      (let ((file-name (expand-file-name (format "page-%d.png"
                                                 (doc-view-current-page))
                                         (doc-view-current-cache-dir))))
        (call-process-shell-command
         "convert" nil nil nil "-negate" file-name file-name)
        (clear-image-cache)
        (doc-view-goto-page (doc-view-current-page))))))

(defun doc-view-reverse-colors-all-pages ()
  "Inverts document colors on all pages.\n
Requires an installation of ImageMagick (\"convert\")."
  (interactive)
  ;; error out when ImageMagick is not installed
  (if (/= 0 (call-process-shell-command "convert -version"))
      (error "Reverse colors requires ImageMagick (convert)")
    (when (eq major-mode 'doc-view-mode)
      ;; assume current doc-view internals about cache-names
      (let ((orig (doc-view-current-page))
            (page nil))
        (message "Reversing video on all pages...")
        (dotimes (pnum (doc-view-last-page-number))
          (setq page (expand-file-name (format "page-%d.png" (1+ pnum))
                                       (doc-view-current-cache-dir)))
          (call-process-shell-command
           "convert" nil nil nil "-negate" page page))
        (clear-image-cache)
        (doc-view-goto-page orig)
        (message "Done reversing video!")))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. Your code is interesting indeed.

Comment: For those people trying to use the above code without success: (doc-view-current-cache-dir)
should be replaced with (doc-view--current-cache-dir) Very useful, thank you!